# Build Android job with connectedInstrumentTest not working on Jenkins

Tags: java, android, jenkins, android-emulator, android-gradle-plugin

I had configured Jenkins build to build gradle project and run tests on it (using connectedInstrumentTest) but build fail several seconds after start.

### Stacktrace:

> com.android.ddmlib.InstallException    at
>   com.android.ddmlib.Device.installPackage(Device.java:884)     at
>   com.android.builder.testing.ConnectedDevice.installPackage(ConnectedDevice.java:78)
>     at
>   com.android.builder.internal.testing.SimpleTestCallable.call(SimpleTestCallable.java:97)
>     at
>   com.android.builder.internal.testing.SimpleTestCallable.call(SimpleTestCallable.java:40)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) Caused by:
>   com.android.ddmlib.TimeoutException   at
>   com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.read(AdbHelper.java:686)     at
>   com.android.ddmlib.SyncService.doPushFile(SyncService.java:695)   at
>   com.android.ddmlib.SyncService.pushFile(SyncService.java:380)     at
>   com.android.ddmlib.Device.syncPackageToDevice(Device.java:906)    at
>   com.android.ddmlib.Device.installPackage(Device.java:875)     ... 9 more
>
> com.android.builder.testing.ConnectedDevice > runTests[sdk - 4.4.2]
>   [31mFAILED [0m
>
> com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException:
>   com.android.ddmlib.InstallException       at
>   com.android.builder.testing.ConnectedDevice.installPackage(ConnectedDevice.java:81)
>
> null com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException:
>   com.android.ddmlib.InstallException   at
>   com.android.builder.testing.ConnectedDevice.installPackage(ConnectedDevice.java:81)
>     at
>   com.android.builder.internal.testing.SimpleTestCallable.call(SimpleTestCallable.java:97)
>     at
>   com.android.builder.internal.testing.SimpleTestCallable.call(SimpleTestCallable.java:40)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) Caused by:
>   com.android.ddmlib.InstallException   at
>   com.android.ddmlib.Device.installPackage(Device.java:884)     at
>   com.android.builder.testing.ConnectedDevice.installPackage(ConnectedDevice.java:78)
>     ... 8 more Caused by: com.android.ddmlib.TimeoutException   at
>   com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.read(AdbHelper.java:686)     at
>   com.android.ddmlib.SyncService.doPushFile(SyncService.java:695)   at
>   com.android.ddmlib.SyncService.pushFile(SyncService.java:380)     at
>   com.android.ddmlib.Device.syncPackageToDevice(Device.java:906)    at
>   com.android.ddmlib.Device.installPackage(Device.java:875)     ... 9 more
>   :MobileShowcaseApp:connectedInstrumentTest FAILED

I changed emulator configuration and it helps - it can connect to new created device, but when tests are rerun device exception is throw again (reinstaling SDK, gradle did not work).

Comment: Are you able to run the test outside of Jenkins?  It seems that when the test is running in Jenkins that no device/emulator is available.

Comment: Yes, I can run tests outside from Jenkins.

Answer (score 1):

It would have been better if I could have seen your system but this helped me when I was installing http://blog.zuehlke.com/configure-your-android-project-on-jenkins/

This should work fine.Try this. All the best!!